# What happens on a DMA controller when it gets selected?

Tags: dma

I'm trying to learn the ins and outs of an 8237A-5 DMA controller. I've been reading about it and now I've started to design it at the gate level in software. The CS pin is active low. If it gets a high signal on here, do what happens? Do all the other pins just go to high Z? What happens when it gets a low signal?

Comment: Try http://electronics.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: Congrats for doing this project! The 8237 is such a cool machine. I take it that you've looked at the <a href="http://www.intel-assembler.it/PORTALE/4/231466_8237A_DMA.pdf"><b>datasheet</b></a>? What do you need that the datasheet isn't telling you?

Comment: The datasheet doesn't tell me what drives the CS, and the state of the pins when CS is high or low.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data outputs go high impedance to allow other chips to use the data bus -- any operations that occur on the bus are ignored. When it gets a low signal on the CS pin, it will process any bus transactions it sees according to its data sheet. It will then latch the data from the data bus or drive data onto the data bus for a read or write cycle respectively.

The usual hardware design is the CS pin is driven by the output of the address decoder. When the address is seen to be in range for the target device, the address decoder drives that device's chip select pin active. That way, only the target device responds to each bus operation.

Comment: What sends the CS signal, and when does it get sent? Are there any other signals that get sent to it at the same time?

Comment: I think I already updated to answer your question -- typically the address decoder does. Usually any other signals needed come from the processor itself, but sometimes you do need other signals. (For example, if the processor uses a 'read write' and a 'select' signal while the chip needs 'read select' and 'write select'. Or if the bus needs to be multiplexed or demultiplexed. Or whatever is needed to adapt what the processor uses to what the controller uses.)

Comment: So for certain address ranges, the DMA is automatically selected?

Comment: That's the job of the address decoder. It looks at the higher address pins and drives the chip select of whatever device is selected.